# WPF Toolkit Chart Axes cannot be set through Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, wpftoolkit

I am using the WPF Toolkit (`System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`) to generate a simple chart. In order to set my Y-axis to start from a value of zero, I set the `Chart.Axes` property like so:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Width="800" Height="400" Title="Usage" Style="{StaticResource ChartStyle}">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />

</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

This works fine. However, when I try to set this property through a `Style`, intellisense does not even show `Axes`.

```
<Style x:Key="ChartStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:Chart}">
    <Setter Property="Axes">
        <Setter.Value>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I run the code, I get an `ArgumentNullException` saying `Property` cannot be null. This is `Style.Setter.Property`. I looked into the source code at Codeplex and found the `Axes` property:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly", Justification = "Setter is public to work around a limitation with the XAML editing tools.")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "value", Justification = "Setter is public to work around a limitation with the XAML editing tools.")]
public Collection<IAxis> Axes
{
    get
    {
        return _axes;
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(Properties.Resources.Chart_Axes_SetterNotSupported);
    }
}
```

It says here that Setter is public but I cannot find any such public method. Now my questions are:

1. How is setting the property through a Style technically different from the first block of code in this question?
2. Is there a way I can set the `Axes` property through a Style?
3. Should I still be using the WPF Toolkit for charts? Is there a newer "canon" method to generate charts that I am not aware of?

Comment: You have to attach the style to the linearAxis itself, as there is not accessor from the chart style.

Answer (score 2):

you're close :)

You have to attach the style to the linearAxis itself, as there is not accessor from the chart style.

Style goes like this:

```
<Style x:Key="linearAxisStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LinearAxis}">
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Y" />
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

Binding goes like this:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Width="800" Height="400" Title="Usage" Style="{StaticResource ChartStyle}">
<chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>      
  <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Style="{StaticResource linearAxisStyle}" />
<chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes/>

<chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
```

Comment: That way I still have to declare my `Axes` inside the `Chart` declaration and not separately in a style. The main question remains: 'If I can set a property under the `Chart` block, why can't I set it using a style?' Please note I have changed the order of the questions. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Right, so the solution will be my first answer and the explanation is the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering in a new item since you changed the request....

You expect the default syntax to be something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="linearAxisStyle_Alt" TargetType="{x:Type charting:Chart}">
        <Setter Property="Axes">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Setter Property="LinearAxis">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem (which actually isnt one) is that the "Axes"-element doesn't have a style-property. Therefore you can not set a style inherited by its child - the LinearAxis.
That's why you receive the error: "property can not be null". Of course it cannot, cause its not existing.

So the final answer to your request is - (unfortunatly) its not possible.
Hopefully this gives you a better understanding.

Comment: Yes `Axes` does not have a style property. `Axes` is, in fact, a property - a `Collection` of objects that implement `IAxis`, one of which is `LinearAxis`.

Inside the `Chart` declaration, I can add a `LinearAxis` object to this collection. However, I cannot add the same object to the same collection through the `Chart`'s style - that is what is confusing me. It's not that I am trying to style the `Axes` or the `LinearAxis`.

Anyway thanks again.

Comment: I understand your confusion, and you're right with the interface and axis collection. However there is a big difference between setting a property in the app itself, and create a definition of style in a ressource dic. Anyway, I hope your question is answered.

Comment: I guess the answer lies in the difference you mentioned - regarding where you set the property. I'll have to read more in that area. I'll keep the question open as there is no definite answer yet. Thanks

Comment: imho it makes no sense to leave this question open, when there is an explanation why it won't work and the right way to do it. I'm sorry you feeling unsatisfied with this. regards